# Optimization Opportunity through using <link rel=preload> for the service-worker in react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, lighthouse, react-pdf

I am using very wonderful react-pdf along with the webpack. Service worker runs and everything works fine.
However, when i run the Lighthouse tool, it suggest me that i could save upto 8.45 sec if i use `<link rel=preload>` for the pdf-js service worker.

I added the `<link rel=preload>`, but now i want to add it to the `document` when needed. Otherwise it is anyway being fetched again. I don't know what is the best place to do it. Will really appreciate any help.